# How can one convert multiple DVs from long to wide?

Tags: r

Consider the following example long data.frame with two dependent measures, "Score" and "NewVariable", 1 between subjects variable "Prep" (3 levels), 2 within subjects variables "Day" (3 levels) and "Experiment" (2 levels), and a subject identifier "SID".

```
example <- structure(list(SID = structure(c(1L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 
13L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 
6L), .Label = c("S1", "S10", "S11", "S12", "S13", "S14", "S15", 
"S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9"), class = "factor"), 
    Prep = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Group work only", 
    "Lecture only", "No instruction"), class = "factor"), Day = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(14, 14, 16, 18, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 15, 12, 11, 
    18, 17, 18, 17, 10, 12, 15, 15, 17, 19, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 
    16, 13, 12, 19, 18, 19, 18, 11, 13), NewVariable = c(-0.887056411864653, 
    -0.480360621343027, -0.490415963314823, 1.3654758915317, 
    -1.90913204292831, 0.0300532242614742, -1.84822348735206, 
    -0.3813757992351, -1.70572162896999, 1.00321046322335, -0.758813794873949, 
    -0.966033445643038, 0.11876111343571, -1.2312333727132, -0.836123526615442, 
    0.137868615951057, -1.05143917652043, -0.556162009526374, 
    0.112943588135347, 0.519639378656973, 0.509584036685177, 
    2.3654758915317, -0.909132042928306, 1.03005322426147, -0.848223487352064, 
    0.6186242007649, -0.705721628969986, 2.00321046322335, 0.241186205126052, 
    0.0339665543569619, 1.11876111343571, -0.231233372713198, 
    0.163876473384558, 1.13786861595106, -0.0514391765204339, 
    0.443837990473626), Experiment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("SID", "Prep", "Day", 
"Score", "NewVariable", "Experiment"), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"6", "7", "13", "14", "16", "17", "21", "22", "28", "29", "31", 
"32", "36", "37", "43", "44", "11", "23", "61", "71", "131", 
"141", "161", "171", "211", "221", "281", "291", "311", "321", 
"361", "371", "431", "441"), class = "data.frame")
```

My best attempt so far would involve creating the two corresponding wide datasets, e.g.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(example,SID+Prep~Day+Experiment,value.var="Score")
dcast(example,SID+Prep~Day+Experiment,value.var="NewVariable")
```

... then manually gluing them back together.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure the example data is correctly set up? Each `SID` has 6 entries, not 3. It seems `Experiment` is currently a within-factor as well.

Comment: The issues you mentioned were present. I think I have resolved them in the new sample dataset.  Experiment was meant to be within, I misspecified it in the initial posting.

Comment: I see. The calls to `dcast()` should then probably be `dcast(example, SID+Prep ~ Day+Experiment, value.var="Score")` and `dcast(example, SID+Prep ~ Day+Experiment, value.var="NewVariable")`.

Comment: This is off topic here and I'm pretty sure it has been duplicated on SO [approximately 100 times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+%2B+reshape+%2Blong+%2Bwide).

Comment: It is not off topic here.  I don't know how many times we went over that on meta in the early days of the site.

Comment: In the early days, things were still being figured out.  For a more recent thread, please see http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/how-to-ask-question-related-to-the-use-of-r.  It quotes our [faq]: "if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain." I would be happy to cast a reopen vote here if you could point out where statistical expertise may be needed. Usually if [tag:r] is the only tag, it's off topic.

Comment: Understanding what a DV is and the data structure involved (between vs within subjects) in a meaningful sort of way does require some statistical understanding.  It is a data processing question that is language specific, but it is sufficiently statistical for this site.  That bar was clearly set very low.  http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584/vote-on-policy-for-r-questions http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-much-programming-here

Comment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-answer-r-questions (note the criteria here is NO statistical content, not the need for statistical expertise) http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276/should-we-unclose-computing-questions

Comment: None of the first three pages of results on SO specifically address the multiple DV issue.  In fact, just adding the phrase "DV" or "dependent variable" reduces the number of results to far less than a page.

Comment: By the way, the correct answer here turns out to be: dcast(melt(example,id.vars=c("SID","Prep","Experiment","Day")),SID+Prep~Experiment+Day+variable) which is NOT provided in the first three pages of results from SO.

Comment: One solid test (although not the only possible one) of whether a question has statistical interest would be if it could be asked in a software-independent way. (If so, I am confident that we could find some descriptive tags for it, too.) If you could make that change to this question, I would gladly be among those voting to re-open it. BTW, I was unaware of your last four comments because you did not ping me ("@whuber").

Comment: @whuber: I've moved the discussion to [meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1511).  It seems more appropriate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `reshape()`, you can reshape multiple dependent variables at once, thus keeping all the data in one data frame. However, you have to work in two steps for two within factors: One transformation for each within variable.

While transforming for factor `Day` in step 1, `Experiment` has to be listed as a between factor for argument `idvar`. This is because, just like the `SID` variable and the between factor `Prep`, `Experiment` values vary within one level of `Day` in the resulting data frame.

```
# data frame "example" as defined in the question
# long -> wide for factor "Day"
> dfW1 <- reshape(example, v.names=c("Score", "NewVariable"), timevar="Day",
                  idvar=c("SID", "Prep", "Experiment"), direction="wide"))

# show part of the created data frame
> dfW1[5:8 , c("SID", "Prep", "Experiment", "Score.Day1", "NewVariable.Day1")]
   SID            Prep Experiment Score.Day1 NewVariable.Day1
13 S13  No instruction          1         11      -1.90913204
14 S14  No instruction          1         12       0.03005322
11  S1    Lecture only          2         15       0.11294359
23  S2    Lecture only          2         15       0.51963938
```

The second step transforms for factor `Experiment`. The variables created in step 1 (`Score` for each day and `NewVariable` for each day) have to be listed for `v.names`. Variables `SID` and `Prep` remain for argument `idvar` as their values are not constant for one level of `Experiment`.

```
# long -> wide for factor "Experiment"
> dfW2 <- reshape(dfW1, v.names=c("Score.Day1", "Score.Day2", "Score.Day3",
                        "NewVariable.Day1", "NewVariable.Day2", "NewVariable.Day3"),
                  timevar="Experiment", idvar=c("SID", "Prep"), direction="wide")

# show part of the created data frame
> dfW2[1:4, c("SID", "Prep", "Score.Day1.2", "NewVariable.Day1.2")]
   SID            Prep Score.Day1.2 NewVariable.Day1.2
1   S1    Lecture only           15          0.1129436
2   S2    Lecture only           15          0.5196394
6   S6 Group work only           17          0.5095840
7   S7 Group work only           19          2.3654759
```

Comment: The reshape2 approach seems to be: dcast(melt(example,id.vars=c("SID","Prep","Experiment","Day")),SID+Prep~Experime‌​nt+Day+variable)